# Binary Representation to a new byte

Tags: java, byte, bit

I'm trying to create a new byte knowing a certain amount of bits

```
char prostie1 = theRepChars[j-3];
char prostie2 = theRepChars[j-2];
char prostie3 = theRepChars[j-1];
char prostie4 = theRepChars[j];
String prostiaMare = prostie4 + prostie3 + prostie2 + prostie1 + "";
Byte theChar = new Byte(prostiaMare);
```

When i do this I get a NumberFormatException value 196.

I have no idea what might be my problem

--EDIT--

Ok I think I might have to give some more details since I wasn't very clear. I'm trying to do an Uuencode algorithm and by following the logic of the algorithm I should stop my byte having a value bigger than 194. Here is a bunch of my code.

```
if(my_chars.length % 3 == 0)
    {

        for(int x = 0; x < my_chars.length; x++)
        {
                if((x+1) % 3 == 0)
                {
                    char first = my_chars[x-2];
                    char second = my_chars[x-1];
                    char third = my_chars[x];
                    int n = (((first << 8) | second) << 8) | third;
                    String theRep = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
                    while(theRep.length() < 24 - 1)
                    {
                        theRep = 0 + theRep;
                    }
                    //0 padded theRep
                    for(int j = 0; j < theRepChars.length; j++)
                    {
                        if((j+1) % 4 == 0)
                        {
                            char prostie1 = theRepChars[j-3];
                            char prostie2 = theRepChars[j-2];
                            char prostie3 = theRepChars[j-1];
                            char prostie4 = theRepChars[j];
                            String prostiaMare = prostie4 + prostie3 + prostie2 + prostie1 + "";
                            System.out.println(prostiaMare);

                        }
                    }



                }
        }


    }
```

And trying to create a new byte with the value that prostiaMare has gives me the numberFormatException. I'm not sure if I have not followed the algorithm right ( http://www.herongyang.com/encoding/UUEncode-Algorithm.html )

Comment: Why are you casting to String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

196 is outside the range of `byte`, a *signed* value. Bytes can range from -128 to 127.

I'm not sure why you're casting to String. If you just want a byte with bits equivalent those of the sum of the four chars, cast directly to byte:

```
(byte) (prostie4 + prostie3 + prostie2 + prostie1)
```

If you intended to construct a String from the four chars, you are not currently doing that. Use:

```
"" + prostie4 + prostie3 + prostie2 + prostie1
```

and, if the result is in the range of a byte, you can create a byte as you have been.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to use the constructor that the Byte class offers.

Answer (score 1):

Bytes are *signed* in Java. Which means a `byte`, which is 8 bits long, has a minimum value of -2^7 (-128) and a max value of 2^7 - 1 (127). Java has no unsigned primitive types apart from `char` (unsigned, 16bit).

Therefore `196` is unparseable --> `NumberFormatException`.

You don't have much to work around this except to read into a larger type and do `& 0xff` to obtain the byte:

```
final int i = Integer.parseInt(theString);
final byte b = (byte) (i & 0xff);
```

Or do yourself a favour and use Guava, which has `UnsignedBytes`:

```
final byte b = UnsignedBytes.parseUnsignedByte(theString);
```

---

But it appears that you want to do comparisons anyway; so just use a larger type than `byte`. And no, this won't waste memory: don't forget about alignment.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String%29)

An exception of type `NumberFormatException` is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:

- The first argument is `null` or is a string of length `zero`.
- The radix is either smaller than `Character.MIN_RADIX` or larger than `Character.MAX_RADIX`.
- Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first  - character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
- The value represented by the string is not a value of type byte.

---

In your case its the last case since 196 cant be represented as byte..The valid range is -128 to 127

Comment: So how may I tackle this to be able to create a new byte ?

Comment: @Bula its any of the reasons above..show us the content of `prostiaMare`

Comment: the content of prostiaMare varies in every loop that is contained in. It has a minimum value of 190 and a maximum of 195

Comment: @fge indeed there's no need to use byte...there would hardly be any reason to use byte..